# How to change selected index item value with ng-repeat in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is my example code. I'm trying long time but not able to figure out.

```
app.controller('homeTabCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.foodTypes = [{
        'filterId': 1,
        'countryName': 'American',
        'foodIcon': 'img/icon-burger.png'
    }, {
        'filterId': 2,
        'countryName': 'Korean',
        'foodIcon': 'img/icon-processing.png'
    }];

    /* Discover live order example */
    $scope.fId = 1;
    $scope.fId.push('filterId': 'India');

});
```

Here i have selected the first index. I want to change country name for first index. How can i implement this one with controller itself.

Answer (score 3):

1. `fId` should be `array` if you want to `push` items in it
2. To push `object` you need to use `{}` syntax.

**SYNTAX ERRORS**

Change:

```
$scope.fId = 1;
```

To

```
$scope.fId = []; // Notice [] Define blank array
```

Change

```
$scope.fId.push('filterId':'India');
```

TO

```
$scope.fId.push({
    'filterId': 'India'
}); // Notice { and }
```

**Example**

```
$scope.foodTypes[0].filterId = 'India';
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to *change* the existing object, you need to [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it first.

```
$scope.foodTypes.find(function(food) {
    return food.filterId === 1;
}).countryName = "India";
```

If you *know* that it's always the first object, then:

```
$scope.foodTypes[0].countryName = "India";
```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your index is stored in $scope.fId field and You want to change the collection object at that index. So use it as below,

```
$scope.foodTypes[$scope.fId].countryName = 'India';
```

Hope this will help.